# Where is the user's profile picture stored in Gnome 3?

Tags: filesystem, gnome, lightdm

In Ubuntu 11.10, I can set my profile picture through the User Accounts settings panel. I can select an existing picture and it will help me crop that picture to look nice.

The final product is not stored in the same ~/.face file used in Gnome 2. In fact, I don't know *where* it is stored and I would love to know! Any ideas?

Comment: I believe one reason why it cannot be stored in the user's home is that encrypted home directories are becoming more and more common.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Pictures are stored in the folder `/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/[user name]`

The [user name] is of type *image/png* format with a size of 96x96 pixels

Under the folder `/var/lib/AccountsService/users` you have a similar file [user name] that is a *.desktop* format - for example

```
[User]
Language=en_GB
XSession=ubuntu
Icon=/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/dad
```

The `Icon=` is not created unless you assign a picture in *Users and Accounts*

If you assign one of the stock pictures the file will contain - for example

```
[User]
Language=en_GB
XSession=ubuntu
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/faces/soccerball.png
```

Thus –as you can see– just create an `Icon=` entry in `/var/lib/AccountsService/user/[user name]` to point to your PNG file or overwrite the icon in the similarly named `/var/lib/AccountsService/icons` folder

Comment: :D That did it! I get the feeling I should go forth and learn about AccountsService, because I keep seeing that name and not paying any attention. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Works also for **Fedora 33** in April 2021.

Answer (score 3):

> If there is no global icon for the user, GDM will look in the user's
>   $HOME directory for the image file. GDM will first look for the user's
>   face image in ~/.face. If not found, it will try ~/.face.icon. If
>   still not found, it will use the value defined for "face/picture=" in
>   the ~/.gnome2/gdm file.

source http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/overview.html.en#facebrowser

Comment: This question should be tagged with gdm also + title

Comment: it shouldn't because the question mentions explicitly Ubuntu 11.10 that doesn't have gdm by default but gnome-screensaver and the control center still have acess, to the image, without it.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using Ubuntu 12.04 the webcam picture taken during install (if not changed) is simply stored here:

```
/home/[UserName]/.face
```

It is stored as a `.png` file.  Go to your <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Show Hidden Files</kbd> options to see it and access it.