# Where does webcam stores clicked images?

Tags: webcam, users, ubiquity

I clicked a picture from my webcam while installing ubuntu. I can see that picture when I am being prompted for a password. I want that picture of mine.

So my question is, where can i find the images clicked by my webcam.

[image]

```
ankit@stream:/var/lib/AccountsService/icons$ ls -l
total 0
ankit@stream:/var/lib/AccountsService/icons$
```

---

edit:- 1

```
ankit@stream:/var/lib/AccountsService/users$ cat  /var/lib/AccountsService/users/ankit 
[User]
XSession=ubuntu
XKeyboardLayouts=
Background=/usr/share/backgrounds/Smile_by_quinn.anya.jpg
ankit@stream:/var/lib/AccountsService/users$
```

Answer (score 1):

You will most probably find it in /var/lib/AccountsService/icons/USERNAME

However, there are some more info about that in /var/lib/AccountsService/users/USERNAME (this is a text file)

Edit: This seems to have been answered before. [Where is the user's profile picture stored in Gnome 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61637/where-is-the-users-profile-picture-stored-in-gnome-3)

Comment: the directory "icons" doesn't contain any file file or a folder.

Comment: Okey, did you check the contents of /var/lib/AccountsService/users/USERNAME?

Comment: yes i did, it contains the contents as shown in edit-1 in my question above.

Comment: Hmm... Wierd. How about in ~/.face or ~/.icons?

Comment: Indeed, .face seems to be png data: `eog .face`

Answer (score 0):

If you physically clicked on a button on your web camera, there's 99% chance it doesn't work on Linux.

You have to install and use a program like `cheese`.

You can install it from the Ubuntu software center.

I think that the images (created using cheese) are saved in the Pictures folder.

Comment: i have edited my question to make it more clear. I clicked the picture as profile picture while i was installing the OS and not after the OS was installed.