# Where is the user's profile picture stored in Unity?

Tags: unity

I'd like to be able to easily replace that picture without using the user interface, by simply copy/pasting it somewhere.  So I'd like to know where it is.

On a side note, I'm not 100% sure this is related to Unity or Ubuntu (I'm using Ubuntu 13.04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking around for that location, and found [the solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/213400/42196) in [another question (specifically related to Gnome 3 though)](https://askubuntu.com/q/61637/42196).

The picture is a simple `png` file named `.face` and stored in your `home` directory.
A simple copy/paste there will do the work: you can check the result in `System Settings/User Accounts`.