# Using CLI, how do I change the user's profile picture?

Tags: command-line, bash

A similar task for changing the desktop background, can be achieved using the following script:

```
FILE="/backgrounds/background.png"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "$FILE"
```

How would I achieve the same result, but with the user's avatar/profile picture?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61637/where-is-the-users-profile-picture-stored-in-gnome-3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is not stored in Dconf.

See the contents of ...

```
/var/lib/AccountsService/
/home/$USER/.face
```

- the 1st will have a desktop styled file
- the 2nd holds the image taken from a webcam in case you used that

To change the 1st check the desktop file for the dir at `Icon=` and replace the file it points to (make sure yours is the same size). The second just requires you to move a file to it (probably in the same size and format).

If you want to remove the picture altogether and default back to no profile picture, remove the property that says `Icon=`, or if you want one single command to do it for you:

```
sed -i '/Icon/d' "/var/lib/AccountsService/$USER"
```

Comment: Okay so if I wanted to change the image inside `/var/lib/AccountsService/icon/UserNameHere/` I would place the image inside that directory?

Comment: @NicholasAdamou I have nothing there :-X But yes, the desktop file seems to point to the file itself so you can just use "sudo cp" to copy over the file (maybe make a backup of the old one too)