# Cannot select file for user profile image in 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, system-settings

Recently upgraded 16.04 to 18.04.

In the Settings app, I navigate to Details, Users. I click the thumbnail for my user account's image.

I am able to select one of the predetermined images that appears, but if instead I click "Select a file", then in the ensuing dialog ("Browse for more pictures"), I can highlight a local image file, but *the "Open" button in the header bar remains greyed out,* so I cannot actually select an image.

Has anyone seen this behavior? Know how to fix it?

Comment: What picture format do you select, jpg, pgn, ...?

Comment: Format doesn't seem to matter; jpg, png, gif all fail.

Comment: And you can open the selected picture otherwise?

Comment: Yes, no problem opening any of these image files in any other context.

Comment: Strange. Do you see the preview picture when you select your picture?

Comment: Oh, interesting: *no*, I do *not* get a preview when I highlight an image file. Useful clue?

Comment: At least it's different from here. I see a preview and can click on 'open'. Do you do all that with your own userID i.e. while logged in with the userID for which you select the thumbnail?

Comment: Yeah, I am logged in as the user whose profile I'm trying to change.

Comment: May be "upgrade pain". This was an upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, and it appears that this little detail was broken during the upgrade. Would it work if you double-click the file rather than clicking the Open button? Alternatively, you may try changing your user picture using the terminal (requires root access): https://askubuntu.com/questions/783680/using-cli-how-do-i-change-the-users-profile-picture

Comment: This definitely was upgrade pain -- and a recent code update from Canonical seems to have solved the problem.