# 18.04 User tab doesn't show any users

Tags: 18.04, users

[image: Image of settings details window, unlocked with no users]

I recently upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04, and I found that I couldn't view any of the other login-able users.

Unlike this question: [Cannot select file for user profile image in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045678/cannot-select-file-for-user-profile-image-in-18-04), there just isn't any users to edit.

They exist when I check `/etc/passwd`/

Comment: Have you tried to unlock and add a new user, and check what is the difference between your old and new added user?

Comment: I upgraded two computers from 16.04 to 18.04. I am not seeing this anomaly. System settings > Details > Users page should at least show the user who is logged in.

Comment: @prosti can't add a new user through this gui (it's unlocked). there isn't a difference either :-\

Comment: @user68186 yeah, I'd have _assumed_ it'd show the logged in user, but, it doesn't show anyone at all.

Comment: @tadiou I have the same issue on `19.10`, could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a "for sure" answer, but I can tell you this.

I'm 90% certain this was due to invalid data from multiple Ubuntu upgrades that never got quite settled. Some config that powered this gui probably was using information that was incorrect. How to update that is a mystery beyond me.

When I re-installed Ubuntu 18.04, everything (obviously) worked fine.