# Removing user photo (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, user-management, user-profile

While playing around with a fresh installation of 18.04, I've accidentally selected a photo for my user. I couldn't find an undo or cancel or remove option, so now I'm stuck with a photo on the login screen. Is there any way to return to the default faceless gray avatar?

My workaround would be to create a new user, grab a screenshot, cut the default image and use that as my new "photo" but if there's a real removal option I'd love to know about it.

**Update**: I did not take a photo with the webcam, just selected one of the provided images, so there is no .face file in my home directory.

Comment: See [Using CLI, how do I change the user's profile picture?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783680/using-cli-how-do-i-change-the-users-profile-picture)  It is in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/$USER`

Comment: @Rinzwind Now that Amit KK updated the answer you pointed to, it covers my question as well. Does this mean you can close this question as a duplicate? I'm a bit of a newbie here. Also, should I mark vanadium's answer (detailed and correct) or sudodus' (points to the older answer which is now also correct)? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no possibility to reset/remove you user photo from the "Users" panel in settings. You need to resort to the terminal and change some configuration settings as root. How to do that is already indicated in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783680/using-cli-how-do-i-change-the-users-profile-picture?noredirect=1&lq=1) (step 1 below), but to fully tidy things up in case you selected your own picture, or took one with your webcam, you should also remove the picture itself (step 2).

Thus, the actions are:

1) Edit the configuration file /var/lib/AccountsService/users/$USER as root user (change $USER to your login name if the variable $USER is not set to your login), and delete the line `Icon=/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/<your_username>`

2) Remove your custom picture `/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/<your_username>` if it exists. It won't exist if you took one of the provided images.

Comment: I had to restart for the change to take effect. Logging out wasn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think your user photo is stored in the hidden file **`.face`** in your home directory

If you remove it

```
rm ~/.face
```

you should get the default faceless gray avatar.

Otherwise you are probably storing your user picture according to this link (the accepted answer by @Rinzwind),

[Using CLI, how do I change the user's profile picture?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783680/using-cli-how-do-i-change-the-users-profile-picture)

Comment: That is the location when you take a screenshot from a webcam ;)

Comment: @Alex, Do you mean the user photo in Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS, or do you mean some other user ID, for example your user ID at AskUbuntu? Anyway, my user photo in Ubuntu and Ubuntu community flavours, that is shown at the login screen is stored as `.face` in my home directory.

Comment: It's also a good reason to not close vote Alex's question.

Comment: Thanks @sudodus but Rinzwind is correct, I did not take a photo, just selected one of the available images in the user edit screen. So there's no .face file.

Comment: See the link I posted at the answer. The picture you pick yourself for a user is in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/$USER` . You need to remove the part behind the `=`

Comment: @Alex I've updated the answer linked to by Rinzwind to also add a case where you want to remove the profile picture altogether

Comment: @AmithKK Thanks, that answer is now complete and covers my question as well.