# Location of 19.10 login screen icons

Tags: icons, login-screen, 19.10

Where are the login screen icons (e.g. "Cancel") stored for 19.10?  Want to get rid of the ugly "Easter Bunny" colors.

Comment: https://vitux.com/8-ways-to-customize-your-ubuntu-desktop/

Comment: actually the cancel you mentioned is not a icon.. its a text from source..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the user's profile picture stored in Gnome 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61637/where-is-the-users-profile-picture-stored-in-gnome-3)